Can a Strictly Hyperbolic System be Linearly Degenerate with Nonlinear Rarefaction Curves?
Consider a system of conservation laws given by:
$$u_t + f(u)_x = 0,$$
where $f(u)$ is a vector-valued function. Assume that the system is strictly hyperbolic, meaning the Jacobian matrix $Df(u)$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues.
Specifically, let $f(u) = Au$, where $A$ is a constant matrix. In this scenario, the system is linearly degenerate because the eigenvalues of $A$ are constant, and the corresponding rarefaction curves are given by:
$
R_i(\sigma)(u_0) = u_0 + \sigma r_i,$
where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues, $r_i$ are the corresponding right eigenvectors, and $\sigma$ is a parameter.
My question is: Are there strictly hyperbolic systems that are linearly degenerate but where the rarefaction curves are not linear functions? If such systems exist, they would have to be nonlinear. Could you provide an example or describe the conditions under which such behavior might occur? Or are the rarefaction curves of linearly degenerate systems always straight lines?
